# If saving equals investment, can there ever be a stock of savings?

Tags: macroeconomics, saving

National product accounting identities imply $S=I$. Since these are flow quantities, everything saved in a particular period is invested, thus there is never an accumulated stock of savings.

Is this reasoning correct? If so, where do household savings during a particular year (say bank account balances) go?

Answer (score 3):

The accounting identity assumes that anything saved *is* an investment, i.e. something will be done with that saving in the future. It's a bit circular, I know. It's not a lagged model, i.e. there's no explicit indexing by time of the variables, unlike (e.g.) in the [Hansen–Samuelson model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier-accelerator_model), which uses discrete time. There are also macroeconomic models with continuous time, e.g. [Ramsey–Cass–Koopmans model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%E2%80%93Cass%E2%80%93Koopmans_model).

Actually, there's a little more to be said here (as I may have committed a fallacy myself above). German economist Fabian Lindner [takes issue](http://wer.worldeconomicsassociation.org/files/WEA-WER-4-Lindner.pdf) with those (including economics textbooks authors) who use a one-good model, like Ramsey's to model *financial* savings:

> The fallacies loanable funds theory commits might be explainable by the mis-application of some ideas and
>   concepts of neoclassical growth models – especially the Ramsey (1928), Solow (1956) and Diamond (1965)
>   models – to the sphere of money and finance. Those models are routinely taught in contemporary graduate
>   economics classes (Blanchard and Fischer, 1989; Romer, 1996).
>   The Ramsey and Solow models are models of real investment only. Financial markets, financial
>   assets and financial saving do not play any role in those models. There is only one good which, for simplicity,
>   will be called “corn”. Corn has three functions: it can be consumed, invested and used as a means of
>   payment since wages and interest payments are made with it. Full employment is assumed.
>
> Without money and other financial assets, the only way units can save is to increase their tangible
>   assets, i.e. to invest. Given that full employment is assumed, corn production is always at its maximum in
>   each period. If the corn is consumed, it cannot be invested; if it is invested, it cannot be consumed. There is
>   thus a real trade-off between consumption and investment.
>
> Only under this assumption does it indeed make
>   sense to talk about a limited saving fund which is increased when it is not consumed.
>   However, this trade-off between consumption and investment is not a finance constraint, but a
>   resource constraint. [...]
>
> In contrast to Solow’s and Ramsey’s model, Diamond’s (1965) full employment corn economy
>   allows units to lend and borrow. However, they do not borrow and lend money but again the one good, corn.
>   They face a triple trade-off: they can eat (=consume), plant (=invest) or lend their corn. Here, consumption
>   are not consumption expenditures but the actual eating of the corn. When a unit wants to lend its corn, it can
>   of course not eat it so that it has to restrain from consumption to be able to lend it. [...]
>
> But since in the real world money is normally not eaten or planted
>   and keeps circulating in the economy when it is spent or lent, those models cannot be any guide for the
>   analysis of a monetary economy. Specifically, what is true in a one good economy – units have to consume
>   less to lend and invest more – is fundamentally wrong in a monetary economy.

Comment: Great reference from Lindner.